# Why can't I add new column while iterating a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to add a new column to a pandas df while iterating:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row["newcolumn"] = row["oldcolumn"].normalize() #normalize() is a custom function
```

This, however, leaves my df unchnged. Why is this?

Comment: See Note 2 [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html): *You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.*

Comment: why would you want to add a column whilst iterating row-wise? You could just do `df['newcolumn'] = df['oldcolumn'].normalize()`

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Please explain the rationale with a minimal (but complete) example and we may be able to advise a better workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc` with `df`:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, "newcolumn"] = row["oldcolumn"].normalize()
```

But for [better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002) is better use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) if does not exist some vectorized solution:

```
df["newcolumn"] = df["oldcolumn"].apply(normalize)
```